# How to deal with the categorical varaible that is not in training set (new categories in test set)?

Tags: dataset, data-mining, prediction, categorical-data

I want to create a categorical variable for the **semester** column in my dataset. I have other additional variables with the target-not shown in the table.

**Training set:** include 2016-2017

**Test set or validation set:** include only 2018

**My Concern is when I make the predictive model I will have categorical variables (factors) that do not exist in the training set (i.e SPRING 2018, SUMMER 2018–First SESSION,...etc). Is this will be a problem theoretically? How to deal with that?**

```
  Start         End             Semester
Jan 19,2016   May 6,2016        SPRING 2016
May 16,2016   Jun 25,2016       SUMMER 2016-FIRST SESSION
Jun 27,2016   Aug 6,2016        SUMMER 2016-SECOND SESSION
Aug 24,2016   Dec 16,2016       FALL 2016
Jan 17,2017   May 5,2017        SPRING 2017
May 15,2017   Jun 24,2017       SUMMER 2017–First SESSION
Jun 26,2017   Aug 5,2017        SUMMER 2017-SECOND SESSION
Aug 23,2017   Dec 15,2017       FALL 2017
Jan 16,2018   May 4,2018        SPRING 2018
May 14,2018   June 23,2018      SUMMER 2018–First SESSION
Jun 25,2018   Aug 4,2018        SUMMER 2018-SECOND SESSION 
Aug 22,2018   Dec 14,2018       Fall 2018
```

Comment: Do you have a specific programming question?

Comment: @ markus my question is from both implementation and theoretical perspective, How to deal with categories that are not in the training set. In other words is it a problem if I have a factor that is not in the training set. and second thing how to do it in R? Thanks

Comment: For the R-part of your question, take a look at the [vtreat package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/vtreat/vignettes/vtreat.html).

Comment: ML algorithms works on data having patterns. either your question is incomplete or your data have to patterns. Can you please elaborate your question to get specific answer

Comment: @ Waseem Ahmad Naeem I am using 2 years data 2016 and 2017 to predict 2018 I understand ML algorithms work on data having patterns, my question is regarding if I have an additional factor in the test or validation set(test set) for example if I want to create variable "year" as a categorical variable it will include the years from 2016 to 2017and in the test set I have to put that factor variable 2018 which is not trained wouldn't be a problem? . Let me know if my question is clear or not.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The machine learning algorithms learn patterns in data, if we do not have any repeated pattern then with high probability they failed to provide adequate answer. I think you need to transform adequate information to your model for getting a rational output. Regarding to your research question, it can be different:
For instance, If you want to answer the question of when is the starting and ending time of semester x in year y?
You can convert the semester column into 4 ordinal categorical variables of 1 to 4 for Spring to Fall. In addition you should provide a year column in your data and DD,MM for ending and starting time.

Comment: in case of separating year by making it separate factor similar problem will arise (i.e 2018 will be a new category that is not been introduced to training model)- because I only created my model based on two factors(2015&2016), am I right?, correct me if I am wrong

Comment: This converting procedure enables us to convert our problem from classification one to regression one. As a result, this pattern is the increasing and decreasing pattern among the records space not repeating type of a certain type.
Or for more enlightening, we may consider 1 to 12 for SPRING 2016 to Fall 2018.

Comment: so according to what I understood from your comment it is okay to have a factor 12 for Fall 2018 if we even do not have that factor in the training set (i.e the training set is from 1 to 11), am I right?

Comment: And I think in this case our factor will be an ordinal variable, increasing over time, so that new number will be okay? right

Comment: Yes. And please not that in supervised learning branch of machine learning we separate all problems into two categories of classification and regression. In classification problems, we want to answer the question of how many and which class as a result we should have adequate data from each class to discover the hidden pattern among the data of each class. However, the regression one tries to answer the question of how much. As a result, we attempt to predict the pattern of fluctuation of data via different dimensions. In simplest case, consider finding the relation among f(x) and x.